# Why Linkedin API return 404 when i try to get email address

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I try to get email address of logged user from Linkedin API so I do GET request on: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))` with Authorization header `Bearer access_token`. But I get 404 with response

```json
{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource null does not exist","status":404}
```

Endpoint with profile data `/v2/me` work correctly. What i do wrong?

Sample code not refactored yet, only for get response and request log. Do not be influenced by the names of the variables:

```java
   webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.linkedin.com")
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)))
            .build();
        webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/v2/me").build())
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + facebook.getAccessToken())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(GoogleProfile.class)
            .log()
            .block();
        webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))").build())
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + facebook.getAccessToken())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(GoogleProfile.class)
            .log()
            .block();
```

And my client code:

```js
    const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8082/login/linkedin/callback';
    const scope = 'r_liteprofile r_emailaddress';
    const clientId = 'client_code';
    const responseType = 'code';

    const linkedinLoginAction = () => {
        window.open(`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&response_type=${responseType}`)
    }
```

Maybe it's some problem with user profile configuration linked with email address privacy policy or something?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by added queryParams by method not directly in url :

```java
webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("v2/emailAddress")
                .queryParam("q", "members")
                .queryParam("projection", "(elements*(handle~))").build())
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + facebook.getAccessToken())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(GoogleProfile.class)
            .log()
            .block();
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier and better way is to use the `userinfo` endpoint as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext#api-request-to-retreive-member-details).

This will give you all the required fields in the same response:

```
{
"sub": "782bbtaQ",
"name": "John Doe",
"given_name": "John",
"family_name": "Doe",
"picture": "https://media.licdn-ei.com/dms/image/C5F03AQHqK8v7tB1HCQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/",
"locale": "en-US",
"email": "doe@email.com",
"email_verified": true
}
```